# Why my program executed after I cancel BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am practicing to use BackgroundWorker to do some time-consuming jobs.
My goal is showing all the file paths on UI.

[image]

I press the RUN button and press the CANCEL button after executing it for 5 seconds. It works fine.

Then I repeat the above steps, I notice that "Check_File" is executed for the third time.

I think that it shall be only two times.

The UI shows like below:

> 1. Searching for Files → Many FileName Appear → Canceled
> 2. Searching for Files → Many FileName Appear → **Searching for Files** → Canceled

The following is my code:

```
private void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
  worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
  worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
  worker.RunWorkerAsync(PText.Text);
  worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled == true)
  {
    FLabel.Content = "Canceled";
  }
  else
  {
    FLabel.Content = "Finish";
  }

  worker.Dispose();
}

private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  FLabel.Content = e.UserState.ToString();
}

private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  Check_File("My_Folder_Path", (String)e.Argument, e);
}

private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  worker.CancelAsync();
}

public void Check_File(string Path, string FindStr, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  string v_alert;

  i += 1;

  try
  {
    if (Path.LastIndexOf('\\') != Path.Length)
    {
      Path = string.Concat(Path, "\\");
    }

    if (Directory.Exists(Path))
    {
      worker.ReportProgress(0, string.Concat("Searching for Files...", i.ToString()));

      string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(Path);

      if (Files.Length != 0)
      {
        foreach (string f in Files)
        {
          if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
          {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
          }

          worker.ReportProgress(Array.IndexOf(Files, f) / Files.Length * 100, f);
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      v_alert = string.Concat("No Path：", Path);
      MessageBox.Show(v_alert);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you verify that `CheckFile` has been called 3 times?

Comment: In your click-event you add the Do-Work. This happens everytime you click.

Comment: I'm guessing that you call `Run_Click` on your button click, every time to press it you add another event(for example DoWork ) to your work so on the first time you have 1 event, on the 2nd click you have 2, and so it will execute the number of times you passed through that function, warp it with `if(worker == null)`

Comment: @LarsKristensen I add "i" to calculate how many times it is executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you press the button you add an event to the worker.

```
private void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;                         //<----Happens here
    worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(PText.Text);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}
```

So if you press it once. The worker has one event attached. If you press it a second time, the worker get attached another event. Hes now has two events. Hes runs again (this time with 2 events) and there is a total of three runs.

You should set up the worker somewhere else.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Init the worker here...
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
    worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

private void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //only run the worker here
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(PText.Text);       
}
```

As Shocky mentioned in the comments, you could also remove the existing event before you attach a new one.

Comment: Or remove event delegates before assigning them using `-=` e.g. `worker.DoWork -= Worker_DoWork;`